# Do these two equations mean the same thing?

Tags: absolute-value

Do the equations

$|x|<a$ and $x<|a|$ have the same solutions , i.e

$-a<x<a$

In general , do the two equations mean the same thing , that the absolute value of $x$ is less that the distance of $a$ from the origin , on either side of the origin ?

Comment: $x<|a|$ includes all $x<0$.

Comment: @lulu Oh so they do not mean the same thing ?

Comment: @Aditi no, they do not. the set of solutions to $|x|<a$ is included inside the set of solutions to $x<|a|$ however. (assuming $a$ is positive)

Comment: @John Oh alright I get it . It means $|x|<a$ is a smaller set than $x<|a|$

Comment: The set of $x$ is bounded in the first case but it is not in the second one.

Comment: @Aditi yes, that is correct

Comment: @Piquito okay I understood ! In the second case $x$ can take all the negative values from negative infinity $|a|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a=-1$, then$$x<|a|\iff-1<x<1,$$whereas there is no $x$ such that $|x|<a$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $| t|=\max\{t,-t\}$, the inequality $|x|<a$ is equivalent to
$$x<a\quad\land\quad -x<a $$
whereas $x<|a|$ is equivalent to
$$ x<a\quad\lor\quad x<-a.$$
I suppose tha tthe lack of equivalence becomes obvious from this.